# how to ping two virtual hosts connected to two different virtual switches created in mininet under two different remote controllers

Tags: python

Suppose I have a created virtual network in mininet through python script.The network consists of

Two remote controllers(c1,c2),

Two switches(s1,s2):s1 is under the control of c1,s2 is under the control of c2,both s1 and s2 are connected to each other. 
Two hosts(h1,h2):h1 is connected to s1,h2 is connected to s2.

When I have given ping command as h1 ping h2 -it is showing destination host unreachable.

Please let me know why it is not pinging?
   c1      c2
    /      \
   s1------s2
   /        \
   h1       h2

Answer (score 1):

You have to program the controllers to configure the switches in the following way:

- If s1 gets a packet whose *destination IP address* = IP(h2), the action set should be outport = port that connects to s2
- The same vice versa.
- If s1 gets a packet destined to h1, push it through the port that connects to h1.
- Do similar with s2.

Considering that this solution abstract is pretty straight forward, it is possible that you have not considered programming the controller in the first place. The first thing that would help is going through a small tutorial on a simple (in-built) controller such as POX. The controller code could be overwhelming in the beginning but it really gets quite simple once you get the pattern of the controller code!

I know I'm answering a little too late, but hope it helps the other people who are looking for similar solutions.